# PAGELATCH_EX occures in update query with UPDLOCK, READPAST

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, blocking

We have a queue organized with a table on MS SQL Server 2014:

```
CREATE TABLE [queue].[Messages](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CreationDateUtc] [datetime] NOT NULL
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Messages_Status] ON [queue].[Messages]
([Status] ASC)
```

Stored procedure to send message:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [queue].[SendMessage]
    @MessageBody NVARCHAR(MAX),
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [queue].[Messages]
    (
        Data,
    )
    VALUES
    (
       @MessageBody,
    )
END
```

And a stored procedure to receive messages:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [queue].[ReceiveMessage]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE TOP (1) m 
    SET
       m.Status = 2,
       m.StartDateUtc = GETUTCDATE()
    OUTPUT
       INSERTED.*
    FROM [queue].[Messages] m WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)
    WHERE m.Status = 1
END
```

This stored procedure executes every second to check new messages in queue.
Very often we get blocks (`PAGELATCH_EX`) on this query even if the queue is empty:
[image]

First idea was - diff-backups, but they are scheduled at different times:
[image]

Other queries don't make blocks so often.

1. Am I right that this is due to `UPDLOCK` and `READPAST` hints?
2. Are there other reasons?

Comment: So you have a heap and you have `UPDATE TOP (1)` with no discernible `ORDER BY` - you know that your `UPDATE` is arbitrary and non-deterministic, right? So it might be trying to update the latest row instead of the earliest row? You might want to [change your implementation a little bit](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes, I know about this. This assumption was made consciously, because I don't need strong order for handling messages now. And I'll change this behavior for future tasks soon. Thank you for the link, it will help

Comment: When rows are deleted from a heap, that space is not automatically freed for re-use.  This can result in a lot of unusable space in your database, depending on how many rows are inserted and deleted into this table.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about deleting the rows, so if there's a lot of rows, maybe the status index should be filtered? Haven't tried that but it would sound logical to only index rows with status = 1

Comment: @MaxVernon I don't remove rows when I receive message from queue

Comment: @JamesZ yes, I'll try it

Comment: @JamesZ is that a reason of locks?

Comment: @MaxVernon why you deleted your answer?

Comment: Because I was quite sure it wasn't actually a good answer.  Please take Remus' advice!

Comment: @MaxVernon I tried it and it works! i have no locks any more. Remus' advice is good, but I need to modify my message hadling-process. You answer with index helped now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you use a Status field for messages and leave unreceiveable messages in the queue. Retaining messages (keeping them after process, with a different status) leads to queue bloat, contention, poor plan choices and general slow processing.

Follow [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) and do *destructive* message processing:

```
DELETE TOP (1) 
FROM [queue].[Messages] m WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
OUTPUT deleted.*;
```

Also drop all indexes on the queue. The linked article has details how to achieve fancier behavior like FIFO or Pending.

Use queues only for events, not for state.

Comment: If queue messages *must* be retained, they can be moved into a table on  different filegroup, preferably on a different set of disks, correct?

Comment: @MaxVernon that's what I mean by 'keep events, not state'. After the event is consumed (ie. message is deleted), if you wish to keep the history (=state), keep it whenever you wish.

Comment: I'll follow your advice in future. But now I've just added filtered index, because I can't change message processing code right now.